# Javascript won't run on my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have modified this javascript code that I found on jsfiddle. My aim is to display tables when a link has been clicked, and when clicking on a different link it displays a different table and hide the previous table. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
var elem=document.getElementById("loginTable");
var hide = elem.style.display =="none";
var elem2=document.getElementById("loginTable2");
var hide2 = elem2.style.display == "none";

    function toggleTable(){        
        if (hide){
             elem.style.display="table";
             elem2.style.display="none";
        } 
        else{
           elem.style.display="none";
        }    
    }

    function toggleTable2(){
        if (hide2){
             elem2.style.display="table";
             elem.style.display="none";
        } 
        else{
           elem2.style.display="none";
        }    
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<a href="#" id="loginLink" onclick="toggleTable();return false" >Business Cards</a>
<table id="loginTable" border="1" align="center" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td>
           Business card table
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<a href="#" id="loginLink" onclick="toggleTable2();return false" >Letterheads</a>
<table id="loginTable2" border="1" align="center" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Letterhead table
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

It worked on jsfiddle, but when I place it on my HTML page, it won't run.

Any suggestions?

Also, I have no knowledge of JavaScript, I have only modified it and it ran on jsfiddle, but not my HTML page.

Comment: Move your script block to just before the `</body>` tag and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Do you have an error in your navigator inspector ?

Comment: Check if there are no errors in your console. Fatal error might stops JavaScript ona whole page.

Comment: The reason for doing that, so you know in the future, is that before the code was trying to act on elements that didn't exist yet. By moving the code to after the HTML elements you're allowing the page to load first. There are other ways of doing that, but this is the easiest.

Comment: @Andy Ok. I'll remember in future. Thanks a lot. I am only doing work experience right now so I am forced to do things by myself.. especially langauges I have not done before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your script load its not find DOM elements so its not working

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<a href="#" id="loginLink" onclick="toggleTable();return false" >Business Cards</a>
<table id="loginTable" border="1" align="center" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td>
           Business card table
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<a href="#" id="loginLink" onclick="toggleTable2();return false" >Letterheads</a>
<table id="loginTable2" border="1" align="center" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Letterhead table
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
var elem=document.getElementById("loginTable");
var hide = elem.style.display =="none";
var elem2=document.getElementById("loginTable2");
var hide2 = elem2.style.display == "none";

    function toggleTable(){        
        if (hide){
             elem.style.display="table";
             elem2.style.display="none";
        } 
        else{
           elem.style.display="none";
        }    
    }

    function toggleTable2(){
        if (hide2){
             elem2.style.display="table";
             elem.style.display="none";
        } 
        else{
           elem2.style.display="none";
        }    
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

if you want to use script in head section you need to write window.onload function

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){

// your JS code 

}
</script>
```